# Handling CSP Errors

Tags: node.js, https, content-security-policy

I am writing a client program to connect to a website over HTTP/HTTPS. The program first tries to connect to the server using HTTPS. However, after receiving a response status code of 301, I tried handling the request with HTTP whenever there is a 301 by making a new request to the HTTP server. As is commonly done to consume data, I added a listener callback on the 'data' event of the http.get() using the on method of http.clientRequest. However, there is no data in the console output. I am suspecting this is due to the following CSP header that I have been receiving with requests:

### Message Headers:

content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

location: http://www.whoscored.com/

server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0

strict-transport-security: max-age=16070400

content-security-policy: frame-ancestors *.whoscored.com; upgrade-insecure-requests;

x-content-security-policy: frame-ancestors *.whoscored.com; upgrade-insecure-requests;

date: Sun, 29 Oct 2017 02:44:33 GMT

connection: close

content-length: 148

Logging the data:

The code is provided below:

```
Https.get(options, (res: Http.IncomingMessage): void => {
  logger.log('HTTPS Client for ScrapeX');
  logger.log('-------------------------');
  logger.logHeaders(res.headers);
  switch(res.statusCode) {
      case 200:
          (() => {
              //
              logger.log('The connection was established successfully');

          })();
          break;
      case 301:
          (() => {
              // fallback to http
              let buf = '';
              httpClient((res1) => {
                  logger.log('HTTP Client');
                  logger.log('----------------');
                  logger.logHeaders(res1.headers);
              }, n_options)
              .on('error', (err) => {
                  logger.log('Error: ' + err.message);
                  logger.printStack(err);
              })
              .on('data', (chunk: string): void => {
                  buf += chunk;
              })
              .on('close', () => {
                  logger.log('Logging the data: ');
                  logger.log(buf);
              });
          })();
          break;
  }
})
.on('error', (err) => {
  logger.log(err.message);
  logger.log(err.stack);
})
.on('close', () => {
  logger.log('Connection closed');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't connect to that server with HTTP, that's your problem; it's using both `upgrade-insecure-requests` and more importantly `strict-transport-security`. Any browser that respects `strict-transport-security` will simply refuse to connect over unsecured HTTP.

Not sure what to tell you beyond in this case you simply can't retry in HTTP, or at least, it'll always give either an error or just redirect to HTTPS.

The CSP shouldn't really be an issue, that's for loading other resources while on that page, it doesn't block people from downloading the page in the first place.